# RegEx for extracting a value from URLs

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following string, I would like to extract POOL using regex.

```
/costs/quotes/questions?api_key=b03f8da1faaf643806b1282c0e1177a0c54f3bc7&funnel=12&buttons=btn-dark-orange&category=22&zip_code=76102&phone=888-668-8262&step=1&step1_title=Where can we contact you?&source_position=landing-page-top-start-here-its-free&attributes={"category":"22","service_code":"POOL"}&ref=www.xyz.com/cost-pool-builders-fort-worth-tx
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Being a new SO user, I'll suggest you to please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

This expression might help you to do that:

```
(.*"service_code":")(.*?)(".*)
```

which has three capturing groups, just to be simple to call. You can get your desired data from the second group `$2`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BR2l6L/1)

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BR2l6L/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(.*"service_code":")(.*?)(".*)/gm;
const str = `/costs/quotes/questions?api_key=b03f8da1faaf643806b1282c0e1177a0c54f3bc7&funnel=12&buttons=btn-dark-orange&category=22&zip_code=76102&phone=888-668-8262&step=1&step1_title=Where can we contact you?&source_position=landing-page-top-start-here-its-free&attributes={"category":"22","service_code":"POOL"}&ref=www.xyz.com/cost-pool-builders-fort-worth-tx`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '/costs/quotes/questions?api_key=b03f8da1faaf643806b1282c0e1177a0c54f3bc7&funnel=12&buttons=btn-dark-orange&category=22&zip_code=76102&phone=888-668-8262&step=1&step1_title=Where can we contact you?&source_position=landing-page-top-start-here-its-free&attributes={"category":"22","service_code":"POOL"}&ref=www.xyz.com/cost-pool-builders-fort-worth-tx' col
)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r'&attributes={.*?"service_code":"(.*?)"') AS service_code
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row service_code     
1   POOL
```